# Getting undefined constant error, but it's defined

Tags: php, constants

I'm getting:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ABS_BASE - assumed 'ABS_BASE' in D:\path\include\global.php on line 11

My `global.php` file looks like

```
<?php

/**
 * Load configuration file
 */
include 'config.php';

/**
 * Dynamically allocate base path
 */
$uri = reset(explode("?", preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote(ABS_BASE, '/') . '/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
define("BASE", str_repeat("../", substr_count($uri, "/")));

/**
 * Load misc functions
 */
include 'function.misc.php';
```

And my `config.php` file looks like

```
<?php

/**
 * Set to 0 or comment out to turn off errors
 */
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

/**
 * Defines the root dir of your site
 * 
 * Example values:
 *   /
 *   /shop/
 */
define("ABS_BASE", "/");
```

Clearly, I'm defining `ABS_BASE` before it's being called, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: try using quotes.. preg_quote('ABS_BASE', '/')..

Comment: I tested this on localhost and it is working fine.

Comment: I wonder if it's a problem with my "server."  It's just a xampp install on my Win8 machine.